# VisualStudio project with multiple sourcefiles of the same name?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, filenames

i have a largish C++ project, with source-files organised in multiple folders (on the filesystem).

in two of these folders, i have files with the same name.
e.g.

```
\MyProject\foo\Blurp.cpp
\MyProject\foo\File.cpp
\MyProject\bar\File.cpp
\MyProject\bar\Knoll.cpp
```

the project is cross platform, and i use autoconf on linux and OSX, but have to use MSVC on W32 (due to some 3rd party C++ libraries i use on W32 and the C++ binary interface incompatibilities across compilers)

on the MSVC side, the project is organized into multiple "Filters" (those virtual Folders) as well (with names roughly corresponding to the Directories the files live in), so i can distinguish them.

now the problem is, when i build the project, MSVC puts the object files in a single flat diretory, and i end up with:

```
\MyProject\Release\Blurp.obj
\MyProject\Release\File.obj
\MyProject\Release\Knoll.obj
```

as can be seen, there's only one `File.obj`, so one binary object is missing.
obviously, the linker complains, since it cannot find classes/functions/... defined in that missing object file.

*is there a way to tell MSVC to create object files with a unique name depending on the directories (or filters) those files live in?*

i imagine something like:

```
\MyProject\Release\foo\Blurp.obj
\MyProject\Release\foo\File.obj
\MyProject\Release\bar\File.obj
\MyProject\Release\bar\Knoll.obj
```

or

```
\MyProject\Release\foo-Blurp.obj
...
```

or whatever.
all other build-systems i know (CMake, autotools) are able to deal with multiple files of the same name.

this question is similar to [3729515](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729515), but i'm currently stuck to VS2008.
(the solution suggested there for VS2008 - to set the Object-Directory for each file in question - is something which indeed works theoretically, but which i would like to avoid for practical reasons)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two files of the same name give linker error in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351132/two-files-of-the-same-name-give-linker-error-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set a *file-specific* project setting for one (or both) of the files that conflict and set the "Object File Name" property to:

```
$(InputDir)\$(IntDir)\
```

Just right-click the filename instead of the project name to set the property for that file only.

For example, if you do that for `\MyProject\foo\File.cpp` then the object file for that source file will go to `\MyProject\foo\Release\File.obj` so it won't conflict with the object file for `\MyProject\bar\File.cpp`.

The drawbacks to this are that it can clutter your source tree with compiler outputs (but hopefully there aren't too many), and - even worse - file-specific project settings tend to get forgotten/hidden since they're not called out in the IDE at all.  If sometime down the road you (or someone else) needs to change things, it can be quite a mystery about why the build acts so strangely for particular files until someone screws around with it for a half a day until it dawns on them what's going on.

I would personally prefer that a project-wide setting of `$(InputDir)\$(IntDir)\` would cause object files to go to directories relative to the source file, but it actually doesn't work well at all as a project level setting. In that case VS still only sets the output directory once and it ends up being relative to the first source file in the list. Then the linker gets confused about where it should look for object files.

Comment: thanks for the input; $(InputDir)\$(IntDir)\ looks promising, and/but i really would like to have that a s a project setting (for the reasons pointed out), preferably even in a propertysheet, so the change becomes obvious. i'm not very concerned about obj-files cluttering my source tree (even though in total there are some hundreds of obj-files generated)

Comment: Well, this solution did not worked for me. I got error something about "cannot find path bla bla bla". So, I came up with another solution: I excluded "fileWithSameName.cpp" from my solution, and added another one, "AnotherFile.cpp" which is inside have the only line: [include "fileWithSameName.cpp"]. It worked for me

Comment: This doesn't work for me in VS 2015.  But the slightly different property value suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695174/visual-studio-2010s-strange-warning-lnk4042/3731643#3731643 does work: $(IntDir)/%(RelativeDir)/

Answer (score 19):

Maybe you can set the project wide 'object file name' (Configurtion Properties->C/C++->Output Files) to

```
$(IntDir)%(RelativeDir)
```

which uses the relative source folder of the source files. Note the `%`, but this gets ugly if your source files are located out of your project directory, containing `..\`

Comment: Actually you need separators and a filename at the end. This solved it for me:
$(IntDir)\%(RelativeDir)\%(Filename).obj

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$(IntDir)%(Directory)
```

as "Object File Path".

`%(Directory)` contains the absolute path of the file without the volume and without the filename itself. This solution should work at least in VS 2019 and can be applied to a project directly.